# Exceptions on join where query in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to run a query that combines the jobs and job_functions table, then returns results. Added difficulty is the fact that search[:job_functions] is an array, so multiple job functions should be checked. I've tried different approaches and think there are still two mistakes (at least) in the code.

What did I do wrong?

```
jobs = Job.joins(:job_functions).all
if search.present?
  jobs = jobs.near(search[:locations], ((search[:distance_max].to_i || 20)/1.609).to_i) if search[:locations].present?
  jobs = jobs.where("title ILIKE ?", "%" + search[:keywords] + "%") if search[:keywords].present?

  jobs = jobs.joins(:job_functions).where("job_functions.job_function = ?", search(:job_functions)) if search[:job_functions].present?
```

Comment: for one, this: search(:job_functions) might need to be search[:job_functions]. Second (ILIKE as LIKE). Third "%#{search[:keywords]}%". Fourth where("job_functions.job_function IN (?)", and maybe I'm missing something more

Comment: Hi, thanks, the first point is right. Second point I used ILIKE to be case-insensitive and changed the third point to your style, which seems to be more common now. The problem I still have after implementing the changes is that the join takes forever and I get errors regarding the symbol transformation. But thanks already!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by cleaning my incoming array, which included blanks.

```
jobs = Job.joins(:job_functions)
if search.present?
  jobs = jobs.near(search[:locations], ((search[:distance_max].to_i || 20)/1.609).to_i) if search[:locations].present?
  jobs = jobs.where("title LIKE ?", "%" + search[:keywords] + "%") if search[:keywords].present?
  functions = search[:job_functions].reject! { |c| c.empty? }
  jobs = jobs.where("job_functions.job_function in (?) ", functions) if search[:job_functions].present?
end
```

I used the form_input_field with a collection multiple times for different subareas, which created additional, empty, array entries. The code above cleans the empty ones out.

```
<%= form.input_field :job_functions, collection: t('dry.job_functions.engineering').invert.sort, as: :check_boxes, checked: params.try(:[], :search).try(:[], :area) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
jobs = Job.joins(:job_functions)
```

jobs will be ActiveRecord::Relation object, which you can check by jobs.class

Following will return an array.

```
jobs = Job.joins(:job_functions).all
```

Second, no need to add joins again in last line

Third, use 'in' operator when there is more than one value and should be in parenthesis.

Here would be the updated code

```
jobs = Job.joins(:job_functions)
if search.present?
  jobs = jobs.near(search[:locations], ((search[:distance_max].to_i || 20)/1.609).to_i) if search[:locations].present?
  jobs = jobs.where("title LIKE ?", "%" + search[:keywords] + "%") if search[:keywords].present?
  jobs = jobs.where("job_functions.job_function in (?) ", search(:job_functions)) if search[:job_functions].present?
end
```

Comment: Thank you - I cleaned up my code and followed your thought process, which lead me to solve the whole problem (finally). The issue was due to the empty results I had in my array, which I removed with a block.